# Chain rule in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading a proof of the inverse function theorem, and I'm having troubles understanding a passage:

> We can assume that $J_F = \operatorname{id}$. To see why, observe that the function $(J_F^{-1} \circ F)(\bar x)$
>
> - is of class $\mathcal C^k$, just like $F$;
> - is invertible iff $F$ is invertible.
>
> Applying the chain rule, we have:
>   $$J\left[(J_F^{-1} \circ F)(\bar x)\right] \color{red}= (J_F(\bar x))^{-1} \cdot J_F(\bar x) = \bar x$$

However, according to the chain rule we should have
$$(J_{J_F^{-1}}(F(\bar x))\cdot J_F$$
so where does the right-hand side of the highlighted equality come from? Is there an identity that I don't know?

Comment: You multiply with the constant matrix $(J_F(x_0))^{-1}$/you compose with a linear map. The derivative of the linear map $L \colon x \mapsto Ax$ at any point $x_1$ is $L$ itself, $J_L(x_1) = L$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh that makes sense. But wouldn't it be so only if $F$ is linear? It's not among the hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: No, the important thing is that the map you compose $F$ with is linear. By composing with translations, we can assume that $F(0) = 0$ and that $J_F(0)$ is invertible. Let $A = J_F(0)^{-1}$, and consider the map $G(x) = A\cdot F(x)$. Then $J_G(x) = A\cdot J_F(x)$, in particular $J_G(0) = I$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot, now I understand it. Since no answers were posted, if you convert those comments into an answer I'll accept it.